# Multiple definition error

Tags: c++, class

I have a class file : grid.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10
using namespace std;
class Grid
{
private:
    char **ptr;

public:
    Grid(void);
    void show();
};

Grid::Grid()
{
    // sth ...
}

void Grid::show()
{
    // sth ...
}
```

When I build my main class,compiler fails.

```
|15|multiple definition of `Grid::Grid()'| 
|28|multiple definition of `Grid::show()'|
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is keeping non-`inline` definitions in the header. Either:

- move the definitions to an implementation file
- make them `inline`. This can be achieved in two ways:

  - mark the explicitly : `inline void Grid::show() { .... }`
  - move the definitions inside the class definition, and they will be implicitly `inline`

Also, use include guards (although that would result in a different error).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably including the `.cpp` file instead of a `.h`.

You need to split your `.cpp` into the two files. Have only one copy of the `.cpp` and as many copies as you like of `.h.` (using `#include`).

Your files are pre-processed before being passed to the compiler. `#include` can be seen to simply copy the contents of the included file directly into the current file. `C++` can cope with multiple declarations, but not multiple `non-inline` definitions. Make sure you only have inline class function definitions, if any.